# Google Cloud Big Query , Github Dataset Syntax Error

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to make a query but google cloud gives a syntax error.
I had coppied this code which written in 2017 .
I have no idea about Sql

```
Syntax error: Unexpected "[" at [5:6]. If this is a table identifier, escape the name with `, e.g. `table.name` rather than [table.name].
```

The query is:

```
SELECT
  f.repo_name,
  f.path,
  c.pkey
FROM
  [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.files] f
JOIN (
  SELECT
    id,
```

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error message suggests? Plus, is this the whole SQL statement? As it's incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using Standard SQL -- which is a good thing.

Try writing the table reference as:

```
FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.files` f
```